# Implementing Music Across Activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse, audio, adt

Problem: When I use the home button to close the app the music continues playing. So I manually close the app by killing the activity, the music stops... for a few seconds and then starts again (and this time a restart is in order to turn it off).

MusicService.class:

```
package com.MyApp.App;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicService extends Service implements
    MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private int length = 0;

    public MusicService() {
    }

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test_music);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setVolume(100, 100);
        }

        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                onError(mPlayer, what, extra);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mPlayer.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void pauseMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            length = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }

    public void resumeMusic() {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying() == false) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(length);
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            try {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            } finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

MainPage.class:

```
package com.MyApp.App;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.View;

public class MainPage extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        Intent music = new Intent();
        music.setClass(this, MusicService.class);
        startService(music);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mServ.stopMusic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mServ.pauseMusic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mServ.stopMusic();
    }

    private boolean mIsBound = false;
    private MusicService mServ;
    private ServiceConnection Scon = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
            mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinder) binder).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mServ = null;
        }
    };

    void doBindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, MusicService.class), Scon,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mIsBound = true;
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
        if (mIsBound) {
            unbindService(Scon);
            mIsBound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

(NOTE: I have taken excerpts from my app, so I may have forgotten imports in this code, but all imports are correctly included in the app.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    doBindService();

    Intent music = new Intent();
    music.setClass(this, MusicService.class);
    startService(music);
}
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindService();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]please red : onCreate, OnPause , OnResume

Comment: This is not really an answer. Rather than simply throwing out keywords (two of which the OP used in his question), you should explain what he is doing wrong and how to fix it. Please do this in text, rather than in an image. At the moment, it's not clear how this answers the question.